# Redis server responds 'Resource temporarily unavailable' in multithreading Perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, redis

I'm developing some script in Perl which uses threads (max 10); each thread reads a file, process each line and save the result per line in a list or a hashtable in Redis. Everything is working fine until there are more than 15 threads, some threads die and some others do what they have to do. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Thread 2 terminated abnormally: Error while reading from Redis server: Resource temporarily unavailable at /Library/Perl/5.10.0/Redis.pm line 518 thread 2
```

Like the message says, the Redis server is at the top. The error starts from here (nothing unusual):

```
$self->{_redis}->rpush($key, $data);
```

I'm using Redis 2.4.14 and the [package of Redis for Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Redis/lib/Redis.pm) by Pedro Melo.

Do you think this is a good way to process this data structures? I mean, using Redis with threads? Is there another good way? Or what should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure it will help, but what happens if you use [Redis::Client](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Redis-Client) instead? Using threads with network resources is always pretty hairy.

Comment: Hi! I'm a little confused, but the server is needed in order to process the data structures, and the package of Perl is a client that connects to Redis, or what do you mean?

Comment: Redis::Client is a separate Perl package for talking to Redis that makes use of the newer Redis protocol. I don't know if it will help with the multithreading, though.

Comment: Did you use one redis connection per thread? I think you should, since multi-threading support is not mentioned in the documentation of this package.

Comment: Thanks! I establish a connection per thread and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My error was that I was making only one connection and using the connection in every thread. 
The solution: make a connection to Redis server per thread.

Thanks to Didier Spezia for the solution.